# Bounding image preview on hover to webpage frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have managed to make the image preview on hover work using [this](http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/) but as I move the mouse the preview moves with it and escapes the bounds of the webpage "hiding some of it", is there a way to bound it to only move within the webpage just like facebook's photo zoom plugin?

Comment: Definitely going to need a little more information here. Do you have any code you can post, or could you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us. Just to clarify, do you mean that when you hover over an image that is on the far right of the screen, the preview image opens slightly to the right, outside of the screen area?

Comment: thanks for your reply, here is a screenshot that show the preview image escaping the top bound of the web page.
http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/4420/escapingborder.jpg

Comment: Ok, so now we know what the problem is, but no one can help you unless you show us some code.

Comment: Have you tried the tooltip mentioned in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381695/keep-tooltip-inside-browser-window-without-using-plugins? If not, then I would recommend giving it a go. Otherwise you will have to do a lot of calculation on your own to find the window size and move it around.

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/menisy/GtdM4/) is the correct jsfiddle, and thanks @sarcastyx I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I have use the code in your Fiddle above to create a new Fiddle with some working code that uses similar logic to what the Facebook Photo Zoom plugin seems to be using. When the cursor moves over the top part of the image, the top of the preview image is set to be positioned at the top of the page and once you move the cursor below a certain point on the image the preview image starts moving down the page with it.

There are other factors you will need to take into account, including if a user quickly moves their mouse cursor over the top of the preview image while it is displayed it causes the preview to be removed. I'm sure the workaround for this shouldn't be too hard to figure out though and will probably just require some sort of delay in removing the preview image or checking the current position of the mouse cursor before removing the preview image.

See the code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/f7rJB/2/

Please note that this code is just to show the preview image being prevented from leaving the page bounds and show the preview moving down the page with the cursor moving and is not meant to be a complete solution.

jQuery has some good documentation on finding the mouse position on the page: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Comment: Thanks @kezzman11, this looks like a pretty neat solution. I'll look into customizing it a little further and see how it goes!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. I hope it all goes well.